# What are the bump outs on a Bell 430 helicopter for?

Tags: helicopter

On a Bell 430 helicopter, you'll see what look like short wings on the side. I've seen people fueling in them, so I assume they are fuel tanks, but do they serve another purpose? Do they have a name?

[image]

Comment: From pictures you can also see they contain the side landing gear.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Those are called sponsons and serve a few purposes:

- In a number of helicopters, they hold the fuel tanks; for example, in [Sikorsky CH 53E Super Stallion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sikorsky_CH-53E_Super_Stallion), the main fuel tanks are in the sponsons. From [Sikorsky archives](http://www.sikorskyarchives.com/S-65H-53D%20SEA%20STALLION.php):

> The CH-53E main fuel system was contained in the extended length sponsons. Fuel for the No. 1 and No. 3 engines was supplied by a self sealing bladder fuel cell in the sponson.  Fuel for the third engine (No. 2) was supplied by an additional self-sealing fuel cell in both the left and right sponsons.

- They also serve as housings for main landing gear
- They also serve as mounting points for stores, like external fuel tanks in CH 53E and for mounting torpedoes, as in the [CH-148 Cyclone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sikorsky_CH-148_Cyclone) prototype below:

[image: Ch-148]

Image from [jproc.ca](http://jproc.ca/rrp/rrp3/ch148.html)

Answer (score 5):

They are called [sponsons](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sponson) and act as enclosures for the retractable main landing gear.  The 430's ancestor, the Bell 222, was equipped with the same fairings.

Comment: The [222U](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Bell_222U.jpg) did not have retractable landing gear, yet the sponsons remain. That supports the OP's assertion that they serve multiple purposes.